# Set random password

Tags: cakephp

I'm quite new to phpCake and its principles and would like to know the cleanest solution for my requirement:

I'd like to set a random password when a new user is added.
The new user should receive an email with the password.

I see two possibilities to approach the random password:

1) Set the random password in the controller:

```
$this->request->data['User']['password'] = 'randomPassword';
```

The 'randomPassword' could be got by implementing a component.

2) The random password is set in the beforeSave method inside the user model. But how could I access this password from inside the controller then? I would need this to send the password in the email which is done inside my controller.

What is the cleaner solution? Or is there a better approach?

Comment: I don't see a problem in setting it from the controller, that way you'd have it already for sending it. Do you really want it on your model? Just create a public getRandomPassword() method on your model, and that should do the work.

Comment: Sending password in mail is kinda bad way (I personally don't like mail passwords). Maybe you could send in mail to user link with token, where he could enter his password by himself?

Comment: See http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/08/25/working-with-passwords-in-cakephp/ You can use "tokens" for the user to reset/change his password.

Comment: @walkingRed: At the first logon the user will have to change the password so it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'd do it on a `beforeSave()` callback method.

Details here:  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforesave

You can detect if they're creating a "new" user, as opposed to updating an existing one, then, if they're new, generate a password.  When the user is saved, it will have the password data in it.

```
// User model
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
    if(!isset($this->data['User']['id'])) {
        // generate password here
    }
    return true;
}
```

Per the comments on your question, I don't think it's ideal to send the actual password, but - the above answer would work for generating a token or anything else you want to use.

Comment: How could I access the password of the model from inside my controller?

Comment: You'd let the model make and save the password.  Then, if you  want to get the password, you can do a normal "find()" or any other data-retrieval method you want to get the data.

Answer (score -1):

```
$randomPassword = md5(AuthComponent::user("id));
$this->request->data['User']['password'] = $randomPassword;
```

This will give you a giant password, you can cut to the first 5-10 chars as u wish.

$randomPassword = $substr($randomPassword, 0,10);

Comment: Using md5 to generate a password is not random. If somehow we can guess a user id, it would then be easy to find the corresponding password.